# vaadin: integrate angular js using custom layout

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, vaadin

I tried to integrate angular js application in vaadin by using custom layout like this:

```
VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    mainLayout.setMargin(true);
    mainLayout.setWidth("1380px");
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
    Panel panel = new Panel();

    CustomLayout layout = null;
    try {
         String dynamicHtml = "<div ng-app=\"app\">..........</div>";
         layout = 
      new CustomLayout(new   ByteArrayInputStream(dynamicHtml.getBytes()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("could not create custom layaout", e);
    }
 panel.setContent(layout);
 mainLayout.addComponent(panel);
importJs();

public void importJs() {
String PATH_TO_JS_SCRIPT = jsURL+"?tata=" + new Date();
String script = "try{var fileref=document.createElement('script');";
script += "fileref.setAttribute(\"type\",\"text/javascript\");";
script += "fileref.setAttribute(\"src\", \"" + PATH_TO_JS_SCRIPT + 
    "\");";
script += "document.getElementsByTagName(\"head 
\")[0].appendChild(fileref);}catch(e){alert(e);}";
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(script);
}
```

I import the script js using importJs method.
The first time i access the page, the js file is loaded and it works.
The second time, it does'nt work.
As if the script is not imported.
I don't see what is wrong in my code?
Using Javascript annotation i have the same problem.
I use
vaadin 7.6.5
java 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Js file was only included once and only once during lifecycle of the page.
To excecute this script each time we display the page i use:

```
  if(typeof angular != 'undefined'){
       angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('swdId'), ['app']);"
   }
```

The issue is fixed

Answer (score 2):

Inserting angular code inside CustomLayout is bad idea.

I would recommend to read text: [Vaadin and AngularJS - happy together](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-and-angularjs-happy-together).

There is an add-on available that lets you combine the best of Vaadin and AngularJS: [Vaangular](https://vaadin.com/addon/vaangular)

Comment: Thank you dragan for your answer.
I already read about Vaangular.
I tried it.But it depends on java 8.
I'm using java 7.

Comment: Anyway CustomLayout will not help you. You can alsto try to integrate Angular component as any other java script componente as described in https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html Also I am not completely sure that Vaangular is java 8 compatible only. Are you sure about that?